# Error: unexpected symbol in read.csv call

Tags: r

Unexpected symbol error in R. Please see below:

`Error: unexpected symbol in infants.csv <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\alcos001\\Desktop\\Data for PubH7405\\infants.csv" header=TRUE)`

I'm totally lost to what the unexpected symbol is. Does anyone see it? is it a typo or the wrong command?

Thanks

Comment: You're using `\\` or `/` as a folder separator, right? Even though Windows uses `\`, it is an escape character in R, so you can't write `read.csv("C:\Users\alcos001\Desktop\Data for PubH7405\infants.csv" header=TRUE)`, just `read.csv("C:\\Users\\alcos001\\Desktop\\Data for PubH7405\\infants.csv" header=TRUE)` or `read.csv("C:/Users/alcos001/Desktop/Data for PubH7405/infants.csv" header=TRUE)`.

Comment: It's the extra double quote near the end. Edit: now its the lack of comma

Answer (score 8):

You are missing a comma in your function call. Should read

`read.csv("C:/Users/alcos001/Desktop/Data for PubH7405/infants.csv", header=TRUE)`